# How to omit an attribute of a nested array type

Tags: typescript, types, graphql

I've defined 2 types as such:

```
export type Pants = {
  __typename?: 'Pants';
  id: Scalars['ObjectID'];
  price: Scalars['Int'];
  color: Scalars['String'];
};

export type Outfits = {
  __typename?: 'Outfits';
  id: Scalars['ObjectID'];
  category: Scalars['String'];
  pants: Array<Pants>;
};
```

Now elsewhere in my code, I want to import the `Outfits` type but omit the `price` of the nested array of `Pants` object.

I'm struggling to find a proper way to do so.

I've tried:

```
type Outfit = Omit<Outfits['pants'], 'price'>;
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

If I wanted to import my `Outfit` and omit the `category` I would do something like this:

```
type Outfit = Omit<Outfits, 'category'>;
```

How can I import my `Outfits` type but omit the `price` of the nested array of `Pants` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to map through `Outfits` properties with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to check if the key is `pants` then omit `price` from its type.

```
type Outfit = {
  [P in keyof Outfits]: P extends "pants"
    ? Omit<Outfits[P][number], "price">[]
    : Outfits[P];
};
```